# Multi-WIndow Support block activity regeneration

Tags: android, multi-window

When my app goes to multi-Window mode, my activity gets killed and regenerated. IS this the expected behavior.

I was trying to block this using this behavior?

Comment: Are you handling configuration changes?

Answer (score 0):

Found code to handle Multi Window from Link: https://medium.com/google-developers/5-tips-for-preparing-for-multi-window-in-android-n-7bed803dda64

```
<activity
  android:name=".MyActivity"
  android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize
      |screenLayout|orientation"
/>
```